# Yii: опции виджета

Tags: виджет, php, yii

Есть виждет

```
<?php
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
    'id' => 'mydialog',
    'options' => array(
        'title' => 'Список ваших объектов',
        'autoOpen' => FALSE,
        'modal' => true,
        'resizable' => true,
    ),
));
?>
```

Не могу нагуглить, какая опция отвечает за появление скролла, если подгрженая инфа не помещается в модальное окно.

Answer (score 1):

Это делается через CSS [overflow](http://htmlbook.ru/css/overflow)